Can I create a default trait implementation if the type satisfies a condition?
Is it possible to define a default implementation for a function/method fun_b of trait TraitB in case the trait TraitA is also implemented?
Below I define an additional trait TraitBDerived with supertrait TraitA but I would like this potential default implementation to be transparent in the sense that not another trait needs to be used.
trait TraitA {
    fn fun_a() -> String;
}

trait TraitB {
    fn fun_b() -> String;
}

trait TraitBDerived: crate::TraitA {
    fn fun_b() -> String {
        String::from("prefix ").add(&Self::fun_a())
    }
}


Just do as in the standard library - implement TraitB for all types that implement TraitA, e.g. see Playground
Note however, that you won't be able to implement an external trait for all types, only a trait you define.
use std::ops::Add;

trait TraitA {
    fn fun_a() -> String;
}

trait TraitB {
    fn fun_b() -> String;
}

impl<T> TraitB for T where T: TraitA {
    fn fun_b() -> String {
        String::from("prefix ").add(&Self::fun_a())
    }
}

impl TraitA for i32 {
    fn fun_a() -> String { "TraitA".to_owned() }
}

impl TraitB for usize {
    fn fun_b() -> String { "TraitB".to_owned() }
}


fn main(){
    println!("{}", i32::fun_a()); // TraitA
    println!("{}", i32::fun_b()); // prefix TraitA
    //println!("{}", usize::fun_a()); // not implemented
    println!("{}", usize::fun_b()); // TraitB
}

